# Highcharts, old look of exporting i 3.0

Tags: highcharts

there is some code for changing back to the old look of export buttons even if you're running version 3.0.
It's here:
https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/blob/master/js/modules/exporting-old-look.src.js

My only question is, how do I include this code into my graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just copy that javascript into your own project between  and  tags,

or

you can include it from github in a script tag:

or

You can download it to your own project area and include it in a script tag from your own web server.

The script will load and run when the page loads, so make sure to include it after highcharts.

Comment: Thanks Steve!
I had nu success getting it to work in jFiddle. 
Tried to download/include it and now I get "ReferenceError: merge is not defined" on line 19. That line goes:
defaultOptions.navigation.buttonOptions = merge(defaultOptions.navigation.buttonOptions, {
Is it my version of jQuery?

Comment: Find in that code that `merge` function and replace with `Highcharts.merge`.

Comment: Can you post a fiddle so one can see how the code looks like? I don't succeed with this. Not sure if the old coding with "exporting: {...}" is correct. Thanks for your help!