# Using modified JS version in Highcharts to bring back the pre-3.0 export buttons

Tags: button, highcharts, export

There are a few posts on this issue, but [only one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15681368/highcharts-old-look-of-exporting-i-3-0) got me closer to the solution by using a [modified Javascript lib](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/blob/master/js/modules/exporting-old-look.src.js).

But, I don't succeed in getting back the two buttons (print, save).

I have the code to get the libs like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="Highcharts-3/js/highcharts.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="Highcharts-3/js/modules/exporting-old-look.src.js"></script>
```

And I have the Highcharts code like this:

```
exporting:
{
    enabled: true,
    buttons:
    {
        exportButton:
        {
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'bottom',
            y: -20
        },
        printButton:
        {
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'bottom',
            y: -40,
            x: -10
        }
    }   
},
```

But that doesn't do it...

I've put up a fiddle [here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/luftikus143/wjq9b/7/).

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `exporting.js` file, and remove your exporitng optiosn

http://fiddle.jshell.net/wjq9b/8/

Comment: Thanks so much Sebastian! Wonderful.

Comment: Hi Sebastian. Only now I am realizing that the print button doesn't work in IE 8. At least as far as I can see from testing with IETester and what I've heard from somebody else. Could you check and see if modifs are possible? Thanks so much!

Comment: I tested in IE 8.0.6001.18702, could test in native browser and let us not if problem appears,

Comment: And while checking, just realized too that the download button doesn't offer the menu it used too. You can check it out here: http://geodev.grid.unep.ch/megatrends/data/bafu/bevoelkerung_ch.php?lang=de

Comment: And sorry for the confusion: it seems the Print button works, but not, as mentioned above, the Download button.

Comment: Now I see, that download button cause error and doesn't work in IE8. I reported it here: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1964